# pixel identification of corners in an image( checkboard)

Tags: image, matlab, pixel, camera-calibration

I used Camera Calibration tool in matlab but I want to take the checkboard corners this app identifiy and see the pixel values (x y) but in the output (workspace) I see the app identify the points but gives the data in mm, how can I see image corners in pixels in the output data?

Comment: One of the main goals of camera calibration is to produce a matrix that goes from pixels to mm. If you have that, just use it.